# Limit the number of locked rows while using FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED is a subquery?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, queue, locking

Take this UPDATE statement for example:

```
UPDATE queue_messages
SET status = 'leased'
WHERE id = ANY(
    SELECT id FROM queue_messages
    WHERE status = 'pending'
    ORDER BY id ASC
    LIMIT 1
    FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
)
```

I checked with EXPLAIN and found that the sub-query result is locked before the LIMIT 1 is applied:

```
   ->  Nested Loop
         ->  Seq Scan on queue_messages
         ->  Subquery Scan on sub [...] loops=11
               ->  Limit [...] rows=2
                     ->  LockRows
                           ->  Sort
                                 ->  Seq Scan on queue_messages
```

Does that mean there are more than one row locked? How can I make sure that I lock only one row?

I tried this but I don't see `LockRows` in the EXPLAIN plan:

```
WITH _queue_ids AS (
    SELECT id FROM queue_messages
    WHERE status = 'pending'
    ORDER BY id ASC
    LIMIT 1
) UPDATE queue_messages
SET status = 'leased'
WHERE id = ANY(SELECT id FROM _queue_ids FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED)
```

Comment: Read [Locking Clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE).

Answer (score 0):

With `LIMIT 1` in the subquery, it makes no sense to wrap that into an `ANY` construct. That makes Postgres prepare for multiple return values, which leads to a more expensive query plan. Use plain `=`:

```sql
UPDATE queue_messages
SET    status = 'leased'
WHERE  id = (
   SELECT id
   FROM   queue_messages
   WHERE  status = 'pending'
   -- ORDER  BY id   -- do you even need that?
   LIMIT  1
   FOR    UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
   );
```

`LIMIT 1` and `SKIP LOCKED` indicate you are looking for the next free row.  If you are going to process the table until no 'pending' rows are left, and *any* next free row is good, omit `ORDER BY id`. Generates a simpler (and faster) query plan.

This query (with or without `ORDER BY`) **locks exactly 1 row** (if any). Even true for your original! [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE)

> If a `LIMIT` is used, locking stops once enough rows have been
> returned to satisfy the limit (but note that rows skipped over by
> `OFFSET` will get locked).

I tested on Postgres 16 with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (careful, actually executes the `UPDATE`!) I always see a single locked row with any of the discussed queries, in a `LockRows` line like:

```
 ->  LockRows  (cost=25.91..25.98 rows=6 width=10) (actual time=0.208..0.208 rows=1 loops=1)
```

`rows=6` in this example is only the number of rows the planner estimates it has to visit, based on column statistics. `rows=1` is the number of rows actually locked.

Finally, I don't see any way Postgres would plan a `Nested Loop` after removing the unhelpful `ANY` construct.

BTW, your `EXPLAIN` output looks strikingly the same as the one discussed here:

- [Postgres UPDATE ... LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497/3684)